# Run jar file on start-up?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, startup, executable-jar

I have created a jar, it of course works fine. I want that jar to run at start-up automatically. How can I do so?

And now when I am creating bat file with the line

```
@javaw -jar C:\Users\Siddharth Yadav\Desktop\Tic-Tac-Toe.jar
```

it starts cmd for a very short while, then closes it. And the program does not run. The same result was obtained with these lines:

```
@java -jar C:\Users\Siddharth Yadav\Desktop\Tic-Tac-Toe.jar...
@javaw -jar F:\Tic-Tac-Toe.jar
```

Comment: Its different frm other same type question

Comment: Maybe you can take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you understand the question??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**

goto Start/Run and then write = "REGEDIT"

goto HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/MICROSOFT/Windows/Current Version/Run

Add a new String entry. Fill in a name of choice, and with value: `java.exe -jar pathtojar`, where `pathtojar` is the full path to your JAR file.

**2.**

Or you can add your JAR file into START/ALL PROGRAMS/Autostart

Answer (score 4):

// This is for windows platform
use registry editor to add path of .exe file to startup 
goto Run from start menu, type regedit.exe

then navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER / SOFTWARE / MICROSOFT / WINDOWS / CURRENT_VERSION / RUN

on the right side, create a new string value with

name = "anything" and
value  = java.exe -jar "complete path of the file"

press ok to save the registry entry, restart your pc to see effect

Comment: Worked !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: on Stackoverflow, you upvote an answer if you think it is correct.
Moreover, these kind of questions involving operating system(s) must be asked on www.superuser.com (a site by stack exchange only)

Comment: reputation less than 15........ :(

Comment: i've upvoted, u just need only 2 more reputations and then you'll be able to

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!